# hostname.sh ... failed!

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

What does it mean when my raspberry Pi model B+'s boot screen says: "[FAIL] startpar :  service(s) returned failure :  hostname.sh ... failed!

Comment: What is in your /etc/hostname file. If you can't start your pi normally to check try holding down the shift key while it boots to get into recovery mode. The error message in question usually means that their is something wrong with the file I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any disallowed characters from the hostname file. Alphanumeric and hyphen only are allowed, and cannot start or end with hyphen.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

Then also edit the hosts file with the matching new hostname, typically after 127.0.1.1 unless changed

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, fixed it by replacing the `_` with `-`.

Comment: replacing te undeerscore with a hyphen where?